# Finding the closest point(s) by ranking them

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I Have a `N x D` dimensional features, which I need to rank according to their distance to a `1 x D` dimensional vector. Any fast way to implement that in python without recursively apply `argmin`?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at [the closest pair of points problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something really simple is [Squared Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Squared_Euclidean_Distance), and it's implementation would be like:

```
In []: F= randn(5, 3)
In []: t= randn(1, 3)
In []: ((F- t)** 2).sum(1)
Out[]: array([  8.80512,   4.61693,   2.6002,   3.3293,  12.41800])
```

Where `F` are the features and `t` the target vector. Thus the ranking would be:

```
In []: ((F- t)** 2).sum(1).argsort()
Out[]: array([2, 3, 1, 0, 4])
```

However if you are able to describe more on your case, there might exist more suitable measures, like [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).

Comment: @unutbu: Apparently you edited but I can't see the difference. What were those 29 deleted characters? Thanks

Comment: I would have expected a matrix ranged from 1 to 5 according to how close each point with the t. This is not what i am exactly seeking.

Comment: @eat: Sorry, I should have left a note of what I did. The link (something like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) was broken.

Comment: @Abdalrahman Eweiwi: In `Python` indices starts from `0`, so in this case `argsort(.)` will provide what you are looking for, like `((F- t)** 2).sum(1).argsort()`. Thanks

Comment: @Abdalrahman Eweiwi: Did you find my answer anyway useful? If not, please consider to elaborate more on your case, because AFAIUIC my answer provides the ranking you were looking for. Thanks